# Rails 5.1 - How Do I Set "novalidate" for Bootstrap 4 Custom Form Validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-5.1

This is my first attempt in creating forms in Bootstrap 4 using its native validation.

When I execute this code the default error messages appear since I have not set the `novalidate` value.

```
<%= form_tag contact_path, class: "needs-validation", method: 'get' do %>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
          <%= label_tag "#{t :label_name}" %><%= text_field_tag :name, params[:name], class: "form-control", :minlength => 2, :maxlength => 40, placeholder: "#{t :contact_placeholder_name}", required: "required" %>
          <div class="invalid-feedback"><%= "#{t :label_name} #{t :contact_error_required}" %></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
          <%= label_tag "#{t :label_email_address}" %><%= email_field_tag :email, params[:email], class: "form-control", :minlength => 15, :maxlength => 70, placeholder: "#{t :contact_placeholder_email}", required: "required" %>
          <div class="invalid-feedback"><%= "#{t :label_email_address} #{t :contact_error_required}" %></div>
        </div>
        <%= submit_tag "#{t :contact_submit}" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

I have the following with no success. The last one produced the same markup as the previous one.

```
<%= form_tag contact_path, class: "needs-validation novalidate", method: 'get' do %> - questioned if this would work since it's not identified as a class in the Bootstrap documentation.

<%= form_tag contact_path, class: "needs-validation", :novalidate, method: 'get' do %> *** error ***

<%= form_tag contact_path, class: "needs-validation", novalidate: "novalidate", method: 'get' do %>

<%= form_tag contact_path, class: "needs-validation", novalidate: true, method: 'get' do %>
```

How do I reproduce the following markup in Rails to get my custom error messages to appear? I have not seen anything about how to declare `novalidate` in Rails anywhere online.

```
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
```

Answer (score 2):

After over two years I decided to try again. I forgot that I posted this question.

I'm using Bootstrap 4.5.0 with Rails 5.2.4.3.

I took the script from Tyler Fredrizzi's answer and added it to the head section in application.html.erb. I don't remember if the Bootstrap I was using in 2018 required an additional script or not.

Here is my form_tag statement.

```
<%= form_tag contact_path, novalidate: "novalidate", class: 'needs-validation', method: "get" do %>
```

The default popup messages still displayed when form errors occurred. I updated my submit button to remove them.

```
<%= submit_tag "#{t :contact_submit}", class: "btn btn-default", formnovalidate: true %>
```

It took a bit but I finally got it working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your question has been answered but I just ran into the same issue and was able to resolve it by using an html hash in my form_with tag.

```
<%= form_with model: @user, html: { class: "needs-validation", novalidate: true } do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I can't add a comment. On @nlfauria's answer, the key there is to use the `form_with` if you are using Rails >5.0.0.

I can confirm that the Bootstrap 4 validations work with the `form_with` tag and not with `form_for`, which was the default used by Devise. I utilized the same Javascript from the example given on the bootstrap page, which I linked [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/).

If you switch to the `form_with`, ensure that you use `form.text_field` and `required: true` in your fields to match the expected syntax of the new `form_with`.

To clarify, I am currently using Rails 6.0.0 and Bootstrap 4.3.1, so please be aware the expected behavior may be difference.

For `Turbolinks 5.0.0 and >`, in the javascript code that was posted in the Bootstrap Forms page, there a few things to do to make this work.

1. Move the Javascript to `assets/javascripts` and wherever you want to put it. (In the new Turbolinks issue page, there were suggestions of putting the JS in the header to avoid multi-loading issues)
2. Change the `load` event to `turbolinks:load`, as the JS action has changed for how documents are handled. See the code below.

This is in my `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`, as I will use these validations for all of my forms.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    window.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function() {
        // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
        var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
        // Loop over them and prevent submission
        var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
            form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
                if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                }
                form.classList.add('was-validated');
            }, false);
        });
    }, false);
})();
```

*I'm no expert in JavaScript, so if someone has a better method, any advice would be much appreciated.*

Here is the form I used with all of my code:

```
<%= form_with(model: resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put, novalidate: true, class: 'needs-validation' }) do |f| %>
  <div class='form-group'>
    <div class="input-group">
      <%= render 'shared/input_group_prepend_label', label: 'Name' %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "name", class: 'form-control rounded' %>
      <div class="valid-feedback">
        Looks good!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="input-group form-group">
    <%= render 'shared/input_group_prepend_label', label: 'Email' %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email", class: 'form-control' %>
    <div class="valid-feedback">
      Looks good!
    </div>
  </div>

  <% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
    <div>Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %></div>
  <% end %>

  <div class='form-group'>
    <div class="input-group">
      <%= render 'shared/input_group_prepend_label', label: 'New Password' %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password", class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Leave blank if you dont want to change it' %>
    </div>
    <small id="passwordHelpBlock" class="form-text text-light">
      Your password must be 6-20 characters long, contain letters and numbers, and must not contain spaces, special characters, or emoji.
    </small>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group form-group">
    <%= render 'shared/input_group_prepend_label', label: 'Confirm New Password' %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password", class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Confirm you new password!' %>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group form-group">
    <%= render 'shared/input_group_prepend_label', label: 'Current Password' %>
    <%= f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: "current-password", class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Please input your current password to confirm changes.', required: true %>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
      Please input your current password to confirm changes!
    </div>
  </div>

  <%= render 'shared/form_submit_button_custom_label', form: f, custom_label: 'Update Information' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll want something like:

```
<%= form_tag contact_path, { class: "needs-validation novalidate", method: :get } do %>
```

The [method signature](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) expects two args, both potentially hashes, your current attempts are throwing all the arguments into the first hash.

[form_with](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with) is the new hotness, however, so you might consider switching to it.

Comment: I got the same result that I did with my first attempt. The brackets made no difference at all.

Taking a quick look at form_with it looks like that can only be used with models. I will do this the next time I code a form with a model.

Comment: The first code sample in the `form_with` documentation is literally a no model, path only example. `<%= form_with url: posts_path do |form| %>`

Comment: I tried the following with and without the html:. My submit button did nothing at all, not even the default Bootstrap 4 validation.

<%= form_with url: contact_path, class: "needs-validation", html: { novalidate: true }, method: 'get' do %>

novalidate is HTML5 so hopefully I will be able to get this boolean attribute set. At least the default validation works with my original code without the novalidate.